artifacts with instances overlapping with geometry created in nodes
Using Blender 4.2 and eevee. I am getting these all black images when png images with transparency overlap each other. These are instances created in nodes geometry. Eliminated shadows but didn't help.
link to image:

here is a link to the file:
Leaf problem blender file
